# convergence of recursive sequence $a_{n+1} = (1-\alpha_n) a_n + \alpha_n (\gamma a_n + c_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to determine wether the recursive sequence below converges to $0$ or not.

$$a_{n+1} = (1-\alpha_n) a_n + \alpha_n (\gamma a_n + c_n)$$

where additionally $\sum^\infty_{n=0} \alpha_n = \infty$, $\sum^\infty_{n=0} \alpha^2_n < \infty$, $c_n \to 0$, $\gamma \in (0,1)$ and all terms non-negative as well as $(\alpha_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \subset [0,1]$.

This sequence is a simplified version of a deterministic case of a stochastic approximation theorem that I am trying to prove. However, when going through the proof I noticed a circular conclusion. I further noticed, that there is a different proof additionally requiring $\sum^\infty_{n=0} \alpha_n c_n < \infty$.

I therefore have the suspicion that the above defined sequence does not necessarily converge to zero if $\sum^\infty_{n=0} \alpha_n c_n < \infty$ does not hold.

Showing that this sequence does not converge to zero would be a contradiction to the stochastic approximation theorem and thus allow me to easily reject the theorem.

How would I go about to determine wether this sequence converges or diverges?"

I tried to bring it in an explicit form but I failed. There is not much more I can add.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: It is an interesting question but I can see how it might appear unmotivated. How about explaining where it comes from (is it from a textbook/course/problem arising outside math?) and maybe your own attempts at solving it, perhaps it will get reopened. If you are truely completely stuck then try simplifying the problem and attempting to solve the simplified version (maybe \gamma=0 and \alpha_n=1/n would be a place to start - nevermind that \gamma is not allowed to be zero in the original problem - and then try to express a_{n+1} as a_{n-1} and see what jumps out).

Comment: I might have some ideas for the general case if it is reopened.

Comment: You can always ask a new question, answer it and link it here. Doesn't look like this one will be reopened.